# Is the "link" element necessary when I want to modify the style of a webpage with CSS?

Tags: css, hyperlink

I was studying this example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Introducing to CSS</title>
<link href="css/example.css" type="text/css"
rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<h1>From Garden to Plate</h1>
<p> A <i>potager</i> or kitchen garden...</p>
<h2>What to plant</h2>
<p>Plant are chosen as...</p>
</body>
</html>

body {
font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;}
h1, h2 {
color: #ee3e80;}
p {
color: #665544;}
```

The result was I couldn't make any change on my webpage.  The CSS rules don't work. I don't know why. My second question is: Is the "link" element necessary when I want to modify the style of a webpage with CSS?

Comment: You can't just bung CSS at the end of the HTML and expect it to work.

Comment: I'm not sure I correctly understand what you are saying. The HTML and CSS parts in your example should really be two distinct files... Are they? By the way, there is a trailing backquote on the first color line in your CSS; I have refrained from fixing it for you, as this might actually be the cause of your issue.

Comment: I didn't make this example by myself. I found this example in a book.

Comment: See my answer below. I believe this css code is meant to be inside example.css file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your CSS to work, you can do it in 2 main ways:

1. Use `<style>` tag.

You can enclose you CSS code into `<style></style>` inside the `head` or `body` like this:

```
<style>
body {
   font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
h1, h2 {
   color: #ee3e80;
}
p {
   color: #665544;
}
</style>
```

2. Using `<link>` tag.

You already have this  line of code in your example:

`<link href="css/example.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />`

Assuming you have **css** folder with **example.css** file inside it, you can put your styles there and it will work as well.

Usually it's more preferrable to use second variant , because it keeps your CSS in separate file and your HTML stays clean.

Comment: No prob! Fun coding! :)

Comment: Hi VItalii. When I use the second variant I need to download a new programme to open a Css file?

Comment: CSS file is just text file. You can edit with any Text editor. But in common, you will use some IDE to do that. You can start with VS Code: https://code.visualstudio.com/. It's free and have all the features you need to work with HTML/CSS/JS and even more.

Answer (score 0):

No it's not needed. You can replace the "link" tag by the following:

```
<style>
body {
    font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
h1, h2 {
    color: #ee3e80;
}
p {
    color: #665544;
}
</style>
```

But if you want to work with separated html and css files (which can be considered a good practice), then you need the "link" tag